# How are certain columns of the main table synchronized with the child tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables. I would like to synchronize **TaskDetails**'s **task_type,task_status** table with **Tasks table**'s **task_type,task_status**.

I try to set **task_type,task_status** as foreign keys, but it seems not right. how can I do it?

**User table**

```
+-------------+----------+-----------------------+-----------+
| employee_id | password | email                 | phone     |
+-------------+----------+-----------------------+-----------+
| Jone        | password | jone356@microsoft.com | 123456789 |
+-------------+----------+-----------------------+-----------+
```

**Tasks table**

```
+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| task_id    | task_type | task_status | employee_id |
+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| task_3     | type2     | status1     | Jone        |
| task_one_h | type1     | status1     | Jone        |
| task_t_10  | type2     | status2     | Jone        |
+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

**TaskDetails table**

```
+------------+-----------+-------------+---------+
| task_id    | task_type | task_status | user_id |
+------------+-----------+-------------+---------+
| task_one_h | type1     | status1     | Jone    |
| task_3     | type2     | status1     | Jone    |
| task_t_10  | type2     | status2     | Jone    |
+------------+-----------+-------------+---------+
```

Here's the MySQL code:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Users (
    `employee_id`  varchar(128),
    `password`     varchar(128),
    `email`        varchar(128),
    `phone`        varchar(128),
    PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`)
) /*! ENGINE=InnoDB */;

CREATE TABLE Tasks (
    `task_id`               varchar(128),
    `task_type`             enum('type1', 'type2') NOT NULL,
    `task_status`           enum('status1', 'status2', 'status3', 'status4', 'status5') DEFAULT 'status1',
    `employee_id`           varchar(128) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`task_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY(`employee_id`) REFERENCES Users(`employee_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

) /*! ENGINE=InnoDB */;

CREATE TABLE TaskDetails (
    `task_id`               varchar(128),
    `task_type`             enum('type1', 'type2') NOT NULL,
    `task_status`           enum('status1', 'status2', 'status3', 'status4', 'status5') DEFAULT 'status1',
    `user_id`               varchar(128),

    FOREIGN KEY(`task_id`) REFERENCES Tasks(`task_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(`user_id`) REFERENCES Users(`employee_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

) /*! ENGINE=InnoDB */;

-- Insert Values
INSERT INTO Users VALUES ('Jone', 'password', 'jone356@microsoft.com', '123456789');

INSERT INTO Tasks VALUES ('task_one_h', 'type1', 'status1', 'Jone');
INSERT INTO Tasks VALUES ('task_3', 'type2', 'status1', 'Jone');
INSERT INTO Tasks VALUES ('task_t_10', 'type2', 'status2', 'Jone');

INSERT INTO TaskDetails VALUES ('task_one_h', 'type1', 'status1', 'Jone');
INSERT INTO TaskDetails VALUES ('task_3', 'type2', 'status1', 'Jone');
INSERT INTO TaskDetails VALUES ('task_t_10', 'type2', 'status2', 'Jone');
```

Comment: What would a synchronised result look like? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: "_it seems not right_" is not a problem description... What happens with this code, why is that wrong, and what do you want instead.

Answer (score 0):

You use [TRIGGER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) for that pupose

Here is an example for an INSERT TRIGGER and an UPDATE TRIGGER

When you enter Trigger in an sql tab you need DELIMITER in front and end of the Trigger like in the link

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Users (
>     `employee_id`  varchar(128),
>     `password`     varchar(128),
>     `email`        varchar(128),
>     `phone`        varchar(128),
>     PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`)
> ) /*! ENGINE=InnoDB */;
>
> CREATE TABLE Tasks (
>     `task_id`               varchar(128),
>     `task_type`             enum('type1', 'type2') NOT NULL,
>     `task_status`           enum('status1', 'status2', 'status3', 'status4', 'status5') DEFAULT 'status1',
>     `employee_id`           varchar(128) NOT NULL,
>
>     PRIMARY KEY (`task_id`),
>     FOREIGN KEY(`employee_id`) REFERENCES Users(`employee_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
>
> ) /*! ENGINE=InnoDB */;
>
> CREATE TABLE TaskDetails (
>     `task_id`               varchar(128),
>     `task_type`             enum('type1', 'type2') NOT NULL,
>     `task_status`           enum('status1', 'status2', 'status3', 'status4', 'status5') DEFAULT 'status1',
>     `user_id`               varchar(128),
>
>     FOREIGN KEY(`task_id`) REFERENCES Tasks(`task_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
>     FOREIGN KEY(`user_id`) REFERENCES Users(`employee_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
>
> ) /*! ENGINE=InnoDB */;
>
> -- Insert Values
> INSERT INTO Users VALUES ('Jone', 'password', 'jone356@microsoft.com', '123456789');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER after_update_task
> AFTER UPDATE ON Tasks 
> FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
> UPDATE TaskDetails SET `task_type` = NEW.`task_type`,`task_status` =  NEw.`task_status` WHERE `task_id`  = NEW.`task_id` ;
> END ;
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER iafter_insert_task
> AFTER INSERT ON Tasks 
> FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
> INSERT INTO TaskDetails VALUES (NEW.`task_id`,NEW.`task_type`, NEw.`task_status`, NEW.`employee_id`);
> END ;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Tasks VALUES ('task_t_h', 'type2', 'status1', 'Jone'),
> ('task3', 'type2', 'status1', 'Jone'),
> ('task_t_10', 'type2', 'status2', 'Jone');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM TaskDetails;
> ```
>
> ```
> task_id   | task_type | task_status | user_id
> :-------- | :-------- | :---------- | :------
> task_t_h  | type2     | status1     | Jone   
> task3     | type2     | status1     | Jone   
> task_t_10 | type2     | status2     | Jone
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE Tasks SET `task_status`  = 'status3' WHERE `task_id` = 'task_t_10';
> ```

> 

> ```
> SELECT * FROM TaskDetails;
> ```
>
> ```
> task_id   | task_type | task_status | user_id
> :-------- | :-------- | :---------- | :------
> task_t_h  | type2     | status1     | Jone   
> task3     | type2     | status1     | Jone   
> task_t_10 | type2     | status3     | Jone
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=30acfd3f69045a008ebeeb72db9b305f)*